# mongodb Index to find empty values

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Let's say I have a `emails` collection with fields and records like:

```
{
  sendAt: "",
  to: "3432849342332@someone.com",
  from: "3432849342332@anotherone.com"
}
```

If I need to to query only records with **empty** `sendAt` field. Considering this requirement how should I index this collection field? I don't actually need to query any specific dates in `sendAt` field so full index will be redundant in my view. Is it possible to do with mondogb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from MongoDb 3.2 you can use partial indexes: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial.

For example, in your case:

```
db.emails.createIndex(
   { sendAt: 1 },
   { partialFilterExpression: { sendAt: "" } }
)
```

Another approach is to add extra field to documents where sendAt is empty and create a sparse index on that field: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/

```
{
  sendAt: "",
  to: "3432849342332@someone.com",
  from: "3432849342332@anotherone.com",
  sendAtEmpty: true
}

{
  sendAt: "1/1/1980",
  to: "3432849342332@someone.com",
  from: "3432849342332@anotherone.com",
}

db.emails.createIndex( { "sendAtEmpty": 1 }, { sparse: true } )
```